# Eigenvalue Proof Dilemma

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I saw a proof about real eigenvalues for symmetric matrices, I then came across a proof that all matrices have real eigenvalues, which is clearly not true, I was wondering if someone could please point out where I'm wrong. (Sorry if this is a really obvious problem, I am just very confused)

$$ A\overrightarrow x = \lambda \overrightarrow x $$
$$ ||A\overrightarrow x||^2 = ||\lambda\overrightarrow x ||^2 $$
$$ = (\lambda x_1)^2 + (\lambda x_2)^2 + ...  +(\lambda x_n)^2 $$
$$ = \lambda^2(x_1)^2+\lambda^2(x_2)^2 +...+\lambda^2(x_n)^2 $$
$$ = \lambda^2((x_1)^2+(x_2)^2+...+(x_n)^2) $$
$$ = \lambda^2 ||\overrightarrow x||^2 = ||A \overrightarrow x||^2 $$

$$\text{Implies: }\lambda^2 = \frac{||A\overrightarrow  x||^2}{||\overrightarrow x||^2}$$
If $ \overrightarrow x$ is not a $0$ vector (which it is not, since $0$ vectors don't count as eigenvalues), then this division is fine, that means $||\overrightarrow x||^2 > 0$, and $||A\overrightarrow x||^2 \ge0$. This means the whole expression is greater than or equal to $0$, and that $\lambda^2\ge0$, which means it must have a real root. I know that there are matrices with complex roots so I must have gone wrong somewhere, again, sorry if my mistake is super obvious, and thank you for reading my question. :)

Comment: I still don't understand your question. What is $A$? Is it a real symmetric matrix? And what do you want to prove or disprove?

Comment: I'm sorry it wasn't a great question, I thought that real eigenvectors could be scaled by complex eigenvalues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In performing your calculation you used that $\vec{x}$ is a vector with real entries. Hence you showed that if $\vec{x}$ is an eigenvector with real entries, then the corresponding eigenvalue is real, too. Or, conversely: if $\lambda \in \mathbb C \setminus \mathbb R$ is an eigenvalue of a real matrix, then any corresponding eigenvector has an entry, which is not real.

Consider for example the matrix

$$A = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix},$$

which has the eigenvalues $\pm i$ with corresponding eigenvectors $(\pm i, 1)^T$. Observe that the norm of these vectors is **not** $(\pm i)^2 + 1 =  0$, so your calculation does not make sense in this regard.

Observe moreover that your calculation is a bit of an overkill if you just want to prove that "*an eigenvector of a real matrix corresponding to a complex, non-real eigenvalue has at least one non-real entry*". In order to establish this, you just have to observe that the product of a real matrix with a real vector is a real vector.